# warning MSB3270 Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I was trying to move my project from VS 2010 to VS 2013. I got a bunch of warning MSB3270. The DLL mentioned in the message is a third party DLL that we cannot change which was built to target "AMD64" but our project was meant to target "MSIL". It is a decent warning but we cannot change our projects to target "AMD64". Is there anyway just to tell msbuild "turn off this warning, please"?

I tried to set "ResolveAssemblyWarnOrErrorOnTargetArchitectureMismatch" to "None" or "false" as a parameter passed to msbuild (suggested in [this post](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/759796/mismatch-between-the-processor-architecture-of-the-project-being-built-msil-and-the-processor-architecture-of-the-reference)) but that didn't seem to work. Any answers will be appreciated.

C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1697,5): warning MSB3270: There was a mismatch between the processor architecture of the project being built "MSIL" a
nd the processor architecture of the reference "Xxxxxx.YyyyZzzzz, Version=4.112.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=xxxxxxxxxxxx, processorArchitecture=AMD64", "AMD64". This mismatch may cause
runtime failures. Please consider changing the targeted processor architecture of your project through the Configuration Manager so as to align the processor architectures between your project and re
ferences, or take a dependency on references with a processor architecture that matches the targeted processor architecture of your project.